# How to deploy a blackberry app using OSGi

Tags: java, deployment, blackberry, osgi

I want to make a blackberry app installable over-the-air (OTA) by deploying it as an OSGi bundle.  Any ideas on how to setup the OSGi bundle?

I believe I'll need a way to enable a directory listing at particular URL as [well associate the mime type for two file types (*.cod, *.jad)](http://www.blackberryinsight.com/2008/07/08/howto-setup-an-apache-webserver-to-deliver-blackberry-ota-applications/)

Any takers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I was able to figure it out.

**Used the following:**

For the most part I followed the steps laid out by Peter Friese ([found here](http://www.peterfriese.de/osgi-servlets-a-happy-marriage/))

The tweaking required is as follows:

**Tweak1:**
In the HttpServiceTracker's addingService() method one needs to invoke:

```
httpService.registerResources("/blackberry", "/appfiles", new CustomResourceHttpContext());
```

instead of the servlet registration to map a URL to the location of your files.

**Tweak2:**
You'll need to create a folder called *appfiles* at the root of your eclipse project in which you place your blackberry binaries.

**Tweak3:**
You'll need to implement your own custom HttpContext class inside the HTTPServiceTracker to associate the required mime types

e.g

```
public String getMimeType(String name) {
    if (name.endsWith(".jad")) {  
        return "text/vnd.sun.j2me.app-descriptor";  
    } else if (name.endsWith(".cod")) {  
     return "application/vnd.rim.cod";  
    } else {  
        return null;  
    }  
}
```

**Caveat:** In order to install the app over the air you'll need to specify the jad file name as there is no support for a directory listing using this approach.

Answer (score 0):

See [Wireless Application Deployment to BlackBerry Smartphones](http://www.blackberry.com/btsc/search.do?cmd=displayKC&docType=kc&externalId=KB17081) for the details.

Comment: I'm restricted to deploying the app in an OSGi container. That's the part I'm scratching my head about.